# SQL Convert & Cast Nvarchar Time to a decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on a legacy database and need to parse info from one database to another, parsing it into the new database is easy enough but first I need to create the query to convert and cast the following in the legacy SQL Server database:

`WorkedHours(NVARCHAR(10))`  is in text format  07:30

I need to convert and cast this as a decimal ie 7.5

I have searched around for the answer to this but can not find anything that has worked, so thought I would put it out there to see if any of you has any ideas.

Edit - What I should of asked is. What is causing an error converting to an int from a character with a value of 0 when trying to trying to convert and cast a time to a decimal?

Comment: Whats the precision and scale of your decimal value?

Comment: It's basically division, yes?  Divide everything after the colon by 60.  Just have to cast the numerator to the appropriate number of decimal places.

Comment: More than 1 example would be helpful. Are the values always in the format `hh:mm`? Could a value have more than 99 hours?

Comment: @Larnu , the hours in the NVarchar field are hh:mm, maximum hours will be 24

Comment: Is your value an actual "time" or is it a "duration"? Consider carefully the distinction and how you intend to use this value.

Comment: @SMOr it is a duration, it is the total hours worked between 2 different times.

Comment: So you need to convert it to a numeric value which is simple string manipulation. Find the separator (":"), take the left side and add it to the value of the (right side / 60). Many ways to do that as demonstrated in your answers. Think carefully about your precision requirements - your chosen unit is hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason to pull out the date/time types. Just do some simple string parsing:

```
cast(left(right('0' + WorkedHours, 5), 2) as int)
  + cast(right(WorkedHours, 2) as int) / 60.00
```

This won't have any limitations on 24 hours or anything like that. It just assumes that you've got one or two digits before a colon and two digits after.

Comment: Hi, this was where i started as i do not need a date time in the new db, just a decimal, but i still have an error converting to an int from a character with a value of 0. I think it maybe the 0 values that are causing me errors on all of the above methods, so if anyone has a solution to ignore the 0:00 hours worked, this will probably work, i hadn't thought about this being an issue until all of your comments

Comment: @Dave `00:00` is a valid time so I doubt that's what the error is. Are those times using a different format?

Comment: @DaveHughes - This is ***extremely*** important.  Do you have the value `'0:00'` or `'00:00'`?  *(And have you tried my debugging query yet?)*

Comment: @MatBailie i have '0:00'

Comment: @DaveHughes - Then your statement that your data is in the format `'hh:mm'` is false, because that format specifies ***exactly*** two digits before ***and*** after the colon.  Please run some queries, such as the one in my answer, to establish what you are ***actually*** dealing with.

Comment: @Dave I just tweaked it to compensate for a missing lead zero.

Comment: @MatBaile. You are correct, i did state it was hh:mm and most are, i was unaware that there were zero h:mm values in the table that would cause an issue as anything with a value higher than 1 minute is in the format hh:mm, i didn't write the db, so had no reason to think there maybe a couple of random 0:00 hours in the table, but after you told me the statement i wrote was false, i searched the table, found the 'bad' times ran shawnt00 edited answer and it now works exactly as i need, so thankyou all for helping me solve this problem.

Comment: @DaveHughes - Running a `try_convert()`, as per my answer and larnu's comments, an hour ago, would have saved everyone a lot of time.

Comment: @MatBailie I did try that and i got the same error, i also tried the fiddle, i was still getting the same error, but as i say thankyou for asking the specific question of is it 0:00 or 00:00 because that was the actual answer to my problem.

Comment: @DaveHughes - `TRY_CONVERT()` can't give an error, that's the point of it.  So `WHERE TRY_CONVERT(TIME, worked_hours) IS NULL` or `WHERE TRY_CONVERT(INT, LEFT(worked_hours), 2)) IS NULL` would have found the rows causing the failure.

Answer (score 1):

```
DATEDIFF(
  MINUTE,
  0,
  CAST('07:30' AS TIME)
)
/
60.0
```

Works up to `'23:59'` only

***EDIT:***

Based on a comment elsewhere, you have some 'bad' values.

This may find them...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  yourTable
WHERE
  TRY_CONVERT(TIME, worked_hours) IS NULL
```

And as such, this is a safer version of my expression....

```
DATEDIFF(
  MINUTE,
  0,
  TRY_CONVERT(TIME, worked_hours)
)
/
60.0
```

*(Returns `NULL` for values that failed to parse.)*

Comment: Yeah this woks fine when you specify 7:30, as soon as i add in the column name i get the error conversion failed to date/time from character string

Comment: Then, again, provide more examples, @DaveHughes , one's that aren't in the format you specifically state they are.

Comment: @DaveHughes - Which is why there is an EDIT explaining 1) how to find problem values 2) an alternative expression that returns NULL instead of an Error

Comment: Always frustrating when OPs accept something other than the obvious choice   Already +1 .

Answer (score 0):

This should work in SQL Server and an example-string "1101:56" (1101h & 56 minutes) | in general from 0h to >24h:

```
-- Take all hours before ":" and all Minutes (2 digits) after ":" and convert it to decimal.
select convert(decimal,left('1101:56',CHARINDEX(':','1101:56')-1)) + ( convert(decimal,right('1101:56',2))/60 );

-- with column-placeholder "time_str_from_table"
select convert(decimal,left(time_str_from_table,CHARINDEX(':',time_str_from_table)-1)) + ( convert(decimal,right(time_str_from_table,2))/60 );
```

If the source table have NULL-Values, than use "ISNULL" with substitution-value "0.0":

```
-- with column-placeholder "time_str_from_table"
select isnull( ( convert(decimal,left(time_str_from_table,CHARINDEX(':',time_str_from_table)-1)) + ( convert(decimal,right(time_str_from_table,2))/60) ), 0.0);
```

Comment: Why `float` of all the data types..? Time periods are traditionally *not* a good candidate for a base 2 numerical value.

Comment: You are right. Would "decimal" be a better choice?

Comment: I would suggest so, yes.